# Textbook recommendation for linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, book-recommendation

Can anyone recommend a textbook for linear algebra. Ideally one that covers each section in detail that explains everything clearly with plenty of practice questions and solutions.Online material is fine as well.

Comment: I recommend Jim Hefferon's book since is free and online as well. I have heard Gilbert Strang's book is a good resource for non-proof based Linear Algebra. In addition, his MIT lectures are on youtube.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book-recommendation+linear-algebra

Comment: Please check the [previous answers](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linear-algebra+book-recommendation) first. If they don't answer your question, or if you have other specific needs, you may state your detailed requirements here.